# Mocking laravel cache helper

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

Using the [PESTPHP testing framework](https://pestphp.com/), I want to mock Laravel's cache helper but when I try it, I get an error like this:

```
Method Mockery_2_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::remember() does not exist on this mock object`
```

I want to mock the `rememberForever()` method but why does the `remember()` method show in the error message? I also tried to change `shouldReceive()` to another method, but always the `remember()` method gets mocked.

Here's my controller code :

```php
public function index()
{
    $groups = cache()->rememberForever('groups', fn() => Group::pluck('id', 'slug'));

    return view('index', compact(
        'groups'
    ));
}
```

and my test:

```php
it('should return given data on index page', function () {
    /** @var \Tests\TestCase $this */

    $groups = Group::pluck('id', 'slug');

    Cache::shouldReceive('rememberForever')->once()
        ->with('groups', \Closure::class)
        ->andReturn($groups);

    actingAs()->get(route('index'))
        ->assertViewHasAll([
            'groups' => $groups,
        ]);
});
```

Here is the error shown:

```
 • it should return given data on index page

  ---


   Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException 

  Method Mockery_2_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::remember() does not exist on this mock object

  at D:\Projects\Framework\laravel\Kuhaku\Kuhaku-Web\vendor\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery\Loader\EvalLoader.php:34
     30▕         if (class_exists($definition->getClassName(), false)) {
     31▕             return;
     32▕         }
     33▕
  ➜  34▕         eval("?>" . $definition->getCode());
     35▕     }
     36▕ }
     37▕

  1   D:\Projects\Framework\laravel\Kuhaku\Kuhaku-Web\vendor\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery\Loader\EvalLoader.php:34
      Mockery_2_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::_mockery_handleMethodCall("remember")

  2   D:\Projects\Framework\laravel\Kuhaku\Kuhaku-Web\database\factories\UserFactory.php:24
      Mockery_2_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::__call("remember")


  Tests:  1 failed
  Time:   10.12s
```

And when using partialMock:

```
  • it should return given data on index page

  ---

   ErrorException 

  Trying to access array offset on value of type null

  at D:\Projects\Framework\laravel\Kuhaku\Kuhaku-Web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager.php:327
    323▕      * @return string
    324▕      */
    325▕     public function getDefaultDriver()
    326▕     {
  ➜ 327▕         return $this->app['config']['cache.default'];
    328▕     }
    329▕
    330▕     /**
    331▕      * Set the default cache driver name.

  1   D:\Projects\Framework\laravel\Kuhaku\Kuhaku-Web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager.php:327
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Trying to access array offset on value of type null", "D:\Projects\Framework\laravel\Kuhaku\Kuha
ku-Web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager.php", [])

  2   D:\Projects\Framework\laravel\Kuhaku\Kuhaku-Web\vendor\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery\Loader\EvalLoader.php:34
      Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager::getDefaultDriver()


  Tests:  1 failed
  Time:   5.47s
```

Comment: I want to see the full stacktrace of your error?, it could be the way you use the cache in another context that is a problem. You can try to mock it like so, if that works Cache::partialMock()->shouldReceive()

Comment: Have you tried using the `Cache` facade instead of the helper? `Cache::rememberForever(...)`. This is not a solution but I'd want to know if this solves the issue

Comment: I updated the full stacktrace.. and no error logs on storage i also have enabled debug mode.. i have try use facade instead of helpers and partial mock also give an error.. Before i use PEST it work normal. I dont know why...

Answer (score 1):

The `rememberForever` method doesn't exist on the `CacheManager` instance you get by using the `cache()` helper or the `Cache` facade. Instead it's on the `CacheRespository` instance, which you can watch with `Mockery::spy()` to ensure the correct methods are called.

```php
public function testCacheWorks(): void
{
    $cacheRepository = Cache::driver();
    $cacheRepositorySpy = \Mockery::spy($cacheRepository);
    Cache::swap($cacheRepositorySpy);

    // do stuff that writes to the cache

    $cacheRepositorySpy->shouldHaveReceived("rememberForever")
        ->once()
        ->with($cache_entry_key, \Closure::class)
        ->andReturns($some_test_object);
}
```

Picked this up here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10803#issuecomment-625261817